# My app crash on allocating mapview to add subview for self.view

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to add map (mkmapview) to my one of the tabs, whenever my view gets loaded it crash, I tried to add mapview through storyboard and through code and at multiple views, it always crashes, refer my attached image,

Tried to add mapkit in frameworks too :(

Please help

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `self.view.addSubView` instead of `insertSubView`??

Comment: I tried addsubview, insertsubview and through storyboard :(